# dplyr + "meta"-columns: when a column contains names of other columns to use instead of the data

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder if the following question has an elegant solution in dplyr.

To provide a simple reproducible example, consider the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame( a=1:5, b=2:6, c=3:7,
                  ref=c("a","a","b","b","c"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Here `a`,`b`,`c` are regular numeric variables while `ref` is meant to reference **which column is the "main" value for that observation**. For example:

```
  a b c ref
1 1 2 3   a
2 2 3 4   a
3 3 4 5   b
4 4 5 6   b
5 5 6 7   c
```

For example, for observation 3, `ref==b` and thus column `b` contains the *main* value. While for observation 1, `ref==a` and thus column `a` contains the main value.

Having this data.frame the question is to create the new column with `main` values for each observation using dplyr.

```
  a b c ref main
1 1 2 3   a    1
2 2 3 4   a    2
3 3 4 5   b    4
4 4 5 6   b    5
5 5 6 7   c    7
```

I'll probably need to use dplyr for that since this one operation is a part of a longer dplyr `%>%` data transformation chain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple, fast way that allows you to stick with `dplyr` chaining:

```
require(data.table)
df %>% setDT %>% .[,main:=get(ref),by=ref]
#    a b c ref main
# 1: 1 2 3   a    1
# 2: 2 3 4   a    2
# 3: 3 4 5   b    4
# 4: 4 5 6   b    5
# 5: 5 6 7   c    7
```

Thanks to @akrun for the idea for the fastest way and benchmarking to show it (see his answer).

`setDT` modifies the class of `df` so you won't have to convert to `data.table` again in future chains.

---

The conversion should work with any future code in the chain, but both `dplyr` and `data.table` are under active development, so to be on the safe side, one could instead use

```
df %>% data.table %>% .[,main:=get(ref),by=ref]
```

Comment: Also, `setDT(df)[, main:=get(ref), ref]`

Comment: @akrun Yeah, though `df %>% setDF %>% .[,main:=.SD[[ref]],by=ref]` has the weird side effect of altering `df`'s class while not actually adding the new column to it (presumably thanks to some idiosyncrasy of dplyr chaining). My guess is dplyr makes copies even though we're trying to alter by reference. (Note that the OP want's chaining.)

Comment: @Frank  I would use the data.table solution in the standard way though I understand the reason behind the chaining here.

Comment: @Frank Do you know any way to use the `chaining` for the base R solution ? :-)

Comment: @Frank I updated with some benchmarks.  The `get` option with the standard data.table syntax is faster

Comment: I think using the data.table syntax would be even more faster (though it is a preference)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I would pick the previous edit: `df %>% data.table %>% .[,main:=get(ref),by=ref]`. The data.frame `df` is being heavily used in the code and should not be modified for compatibility reasons. May I suggest an edit that incorporates both answers?

Comment: @akhmed Okay, I've made a note about it at the end of the question. Using `data.table` won't be much slower in the scope of a big chain, I think.

Comment: @Frank, thanks! What I really like about `%>% data.table %>%` version is that it adheres to pure functional programming paradigm when `f(x)` is not supposed to be modifying `x` (i.e. function with "no side effects")

Answer (score 6):

We could do this in `base R` with row/column index.  We get the column index with `match`, `cbind` with row index (`1:nrow(df)`) and extract the elements.  The indexing is very fast.

```
df$main <- df[-4][cbind(1:nrow(df),match(df$ref,names(df)[-4]))]
df
#    a b c ref main
#1 1 2 3   a    1
#2 2 3 4   a    2
#3 3 4 5   b    4
#4 4 5 6   b    5
#5 5 6 7   c    7
```

The analogous `dplyr` chain is

```
df %>% 
  `[[<-.data.frame`(.,"main",value=.[-4][
           cbind(1:nrow(.),match(.$ref,names(.)[-4]))])
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(a= sample(10, 1e6, replace=TRUE), b= sample(20, 1e6, 
replace=TRUE), c= sample(40,1e6, replace=TRUE), ref= sample(letters[1:3],
 1e6, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- copy(df)
df3 <- copy(df)
df4 <- copy(df)

akrun <- function() {df$main <- df[-4][cbind(1:nrow(df),match(df$ref,names(df)[-4]))]}
akrun2 <- function(){setDT(df3)[, main:=get(ref), ref]}
Frank <- function() {df2 %>% data.table %>% .[,main:=.SD[[ref]],by=ref]}
Frank2 <- function() {setDT(df4)[, main:= .SD[[ref]], by =ref]}
MrFlick <- function() {getval <- . %>%
                                  mutate(id=factor(1:n())) %>% 
                                  gather(col, val, a:c) %>% 
                                  group_by(id) %>% 
                                  summarize(val=first(val[col==ref])) %>% 
                                  select(val)
                       df2 %>%
                          cbind(., getval(.))}

akhmed <- function() {df %>%
                        group_by(ref) %>%
                        do({
                        eval(parse(text=sprintf("main <- .$%s",.$ref[1])))
                        data.frame(., main = main, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                         }) %>% 
                        ungroup()
         }

 system.time(akrun())
 #user  system elapsed 
 #0.07    0.00    0.07

 system.time(akrun2())
#user  system elapsed 
# 0.018   0.000   0.018 

system.time(Frank())
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.028   0.000   0.028 

system.time(Frank2())
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.018   0.000   0.018 

system.time(MrFlick())
#  user  system elapsed 
#42.725   0.066  42.777 

 system.time(akhmed())
 #user  system elapsed 
 # 1.125   0.004   1.169 


library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun(), akrun2(), Frank(), Frank2(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
# expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval cld
# akrun() 3.732126 3.822714 3.768758 3.784908 3.7490118 3.448839    20   c
#akrun2() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.000000    20 a  
# Frank() 1.457337 1.455412 1.672008 1.493600 1.6575381 3.697565    20  b 
# Frank2() 1.001986 1.005541 1.003171 1.003474 0.9980418 1.013425    20 a
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, it makes sense that `get` would be faster; thanks for doing the benchmarks. I'll switch to that in the  answer with attribution on the assumption you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

The dplyr mutates operates on entire columns at a time which this type of operation does not lend itself nicely to. A different strategy might be use the `tidyr` library as well to make "tidy" data in a long format then do the subsetting. Here's how you might do this.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

getval <- . %>% mutate(id=factor(1:n())) %>% 
    gather(col, val, a:c) %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    summarize(val=first(val[col==ref])) %>% select(val)

df %>% cbind(., getval(.))
```

This does assume that each ref value corresponds to a column that exists.

Comment: Very clever solution! Thanks! I wonder if  `group_by(id)` and subsequent steps are required? Doesn't `col==ref` remove all duplicate `id` ?

Comment: @akhmed i was more worried about the case where ref="x" or something that didn't exist. I've updated the code to at least return NA in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Self-Answer**: Here is one solution I found that may not be the most elegant but it seems to work:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ref) %>%
  do({
    eval(parse(text=sprintf("main <- .$%s",.$ref[1])))
    data.frame(., main = main, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }) %>% ungroup()

df2
```

which gives me this:

```
  a b c ref main
1 1 2 3   a    1
2 2 3 4   a    2
3 3 4 5   b    4
4 4 5 6   b    5
5 5 6 7   c    7
```

I am still wondering if this could be done with some easy `mutate_` instead?