# R: Replacing values conditional on another column AND matching variable names

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

My overall goal is to assign values to a new variable from one of several variables with specific string matches conditional on the value of another variable. More specifically:

I am trying to add many columns to a data frame where each of the given new columns (e.g. 'foo') takes on the value of one of two columns already in the data frame and whose names begin with the same string and end with one of two suffixes (e.g. 'foo.2009' and 'foo.2014') conditional on the value of another column (e.g. 'year'). The data frame also contains columns unrelated to this operation and these are identified by their lack of suffixes (e.g. 'other_example' do not end in '.2009' or '.2014') and I have created a vector of the names of the new columns. In the below example data, I want to assign values to `foo` from `foo.2014` if `year >=2014` and from `foo.2009` if `year < 2014`.

```
# Original data frame
df <- data.frame( foo.2009 = seq(1,3),
                  foo.2014 = seq(5,7),
                  foo = NA,
                  bar = NA,
                  other_example = seq(20,22),
                  year = c(2014,2009,2014))
print(df)

# The vector of variable names ending in '.####`
names <- c("foo")

# Target data frame
df$foo <- c(5,2,7)
print(df)
```

In my real data, I have many variables (e.g. `bar`) similar to `foo` where I want `bar == bar.2014` if `year >= 2014` and `bar == bar.2009` if `year < 2014`. I am therefore trying to develop a solution where I can loop through (or use vectorized operations on) a vector of variable names (e.g. `names`) for an arbitrarily large number of variables where I want to replace the values:

```
# The vector of variable names ending in `.####`
names <- c("foo","bar")

# Original data frame
df <- data.frame( foo.2009 = seq(1,3),
                  foo.2014 = seq(5,7),
                  bar.2009 = seq(8,10),
                  bar.2014 = rep(5,3),
                  foo = NA,
                  bar = NA,
                  other_example = seq(20,22),
                  year = c(2014,2009,2014))
df

# Target data frame
df$foo <-  c(5,2,7)
df$bar <- c(5,9,5)
df
```

I am particularly having trouble with the need to evaluate multiple strings comprising variable names in a loop or using a vectorized approach. An attempt is below using dplyr::mutate() to add the variables then assign them values. Below is the same data as above but an example of what an additional variable to recode would look like.

```
library(dplyr)

for (i in names){
  var09 <- paste0(i, ".2009")
  var14 <- paste0(i, ".2014")
  dplyr::mutate_(df,
                 i = ifelse(df$year < 2010,
                            paste0("df$",i, ".2009"),
                            paste0("df$",i, ".2014")))}
```

Comment: Don't store variables in column names; reshape to long form instead, and you'll avoid these convolutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to provide data to someone in this format and therefore I cannot provide the data to the person in long form.

Comment: This solution might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30271447/3893729

Comment: @QuestionAnswer Give that person [some reading](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). You probably still want to tidy your data for intermediary purposes; you can muck it up at the end, if necessary.

Comment: MFR comments are helpful, the other comments above are not constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the sequence in `base R`

```
nm1 <- c("foo\\.\\d+", "bar\\.\\d+")
nm2 <- c("foo", "bar")
for(j in seq_along(nm1)){
  sub1 <- df[grep(nm1[j], names(df))]
  df[[nm2[j]]] <- ifelse(df$year < 2010, sub1[[1]], sub1[[2]])
 }

df
#   foo.2009 foo.2014 bar.2009 bar.2014 foo bar other_example year
#1        1        5        8        5   5   5            20 2014
#2        2        6        9        5   2   9            21 2009
#3        3        7       10        5   7   5            22 2014
```